# How can we assign a field of user table say id that is primary key, to another table as a primary key? using hibernate

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

See I dont want any mapping but what I want is just a simple thing that is....

I have two Entity

1. Tasks(taskid,taskname.....,userId)
2. User_Credentials(userId,password)

So What I want is userId of User Credentials used as a foreign key in Task table.

So when I fire an api to save the task I have to also pass the all details of user Credentials That I dont want.

```
    {
    "taskName": "Test",
    "taskStatus": "Open",
    "taskDueDate": "2022-04-15",
    "taskCreatedDate": "2022-04-10",
    "taskDescription": "Demo",
    "taskPriority": "High",
    "isTaskActive": "Yes",
    "userCredentials":{
        "associateId":"108",
        "password":"something@9122"
    }
  }
```

What I want is

```
   {
    "taskName": "Test",
    "taskStatus": "Open",
    "taskDueDate": "2022-04-15",
    "taskCreatedDate": "2022-04-10",
    "taskDescription": "Demo",
    "taskPriority": "High",
    "isTaskActive": "Yes",
    "userCredentials":"108"
```

}

That I want to post and if userCredentials id 108 is not in User Credentials Table so it pop up an error and if it is there it will save just like a foreign key concept.

So please tell me ho to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ElementCollection to achieve this.

In Tasks entity

```
@Id
@Column(name = "task_id")
private Integer id;

@ElementCollection  
@CollectionTable(name = "task_user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", nullable = false))  
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)  
private List<Integer> userCredentials;
```

In UserCredentials entity

```
@Id  
@Column(name = "user_id")  
private Integer id;
```

UserCredentials is an independent entity with no mapping with Tasks. You will now be able to pass UserCredentials like this `userCredentials: [108]` in the Tasks.

Add the following in your application.yml to generate the create.sql script with ddl commands for all the entities. `ddl-auto: validate` will restrict hibernate from creating the tables on its own.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    properties:
      javax:
        persistence:
          schema-generation:
            create-source: metadata
            scripts:
              action: create
              create-target: create.sql
    generate-ddl: true
```

The following is the ddl command to add foreign key constraints for tables user_credentials and tasks. Execute it alongwith the create.sql in any DB client.

```
CREATE TABLE "task_user"
(   "user_id" integer ,
    "task_id" integer,
    PRIMARY KEY ("user_id","task_id"),
    CONSTRAINT user_id_fkey
        FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "user_credentials" ("user_id"),
    CONSTRAINT task_id_fkey
        FOREIGN KEY ("task_id") REFERENCES "tasks" ("task_id")
);
```

***Note**: The create.sql already has a task_user create command but it needs to be replaced with the above command.*

Comment: "userCredentials":{
        "associateId":"109",
        "password":"Ravi@1234",
        "isAssociateActive":"Yes"
    } Still I have to pass like this its not working I just want to pass userCredentials:"108" if Id 108 already present in UserCredentials then it accept other wise throw an error.

Comment: I understand the concept but the last code block where We have to create table how to create it manually I mean in spring boot we declare @Entity and it will automatically created so can you please edit once more.